# htaccess url'redirects and rewrites

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Hope someone can help me out 'cause I utterly suck at .htaccess tweaking.

I'm developing a php based site. On this site I include specific pages based on a query string

eg: **index.php?q=somePage.**

In the .htaccess I look for eg: **/somepage/** and tell the server to load **q=somePage**. When this is done the server strips all other query strings from the url ergo it does not pass them.

Now to the question, is there someway to setup the .htaccess to catch the **[q]** parameter and pass along all other querystrings (server side)?

eg: if I call **/somepage&parameter=someparameter** or **/somepage/&parameter=someparameter** the server will rewrite the url to **/somepage/** but call the page (serverside) like so:

**index.php?q=somePage&parameter=someparameter**

Here's how my htaccess looks now:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?q=$1
```

if not I guess I'll just have to store the parameters in a session and pass 'em that way. But I hope someone can help :)

*PS: If you know of a book that deals with the htaccess and can bring me from complete n00b to expert, it would be epic if you could point me in the right direction. the same actually goes for regEx ;)*

Comment: Please wrap code appropriately. It will assist those trying to help you.

Comment: sry notised it just after I posted :)

Comment: Well noted, but wrap *all* code, not just your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: not really any other code in there but I formatted the URL's/query string examples in bold to help with quick scanning the text :)

Comment: Helps, but try wrapping them in accents instead. (`)

Answer (score 0):

Usual lot of framework move the logic of *parsing the request* **inside** the PHP

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If the URL not identify a file or e dir, pass it to index.php

EDIT
You can see http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm for an introduction to regexp, but the suggest htaccess pass ALL the parameters to index PHP.

Use *phpinfo();* to see how your reqest is seen by PHP

As your request here the **index.php**

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

here some query you can try (I suppose your code on root of localhost):

```
http://localhost/
http://localhost/test
http://localhost/a/b
http://localhost/?p1=v1&p2&v2&p3&p4
http://localhost/a/b?p1=v1&p2&v2&p3&p4
http://localhost/a/b/?p1=v1&p2&v2&p3&p4
```

Comment: I know I am a n00b at all of this url-rewrite stuff.. but you completely lost me :)

Comment: Easy, set the .htacces in example, put an index.php with ONLY phpinfo(), do some query (param1=val1&param2&...) and see the results. Inside the phpinfo() page there's a lot of stuff, but finding param1 in all page you cand find how PHP and apache saw your requests

Comment: hehe I don't doubt that your a complete htaccess ninja, but I would like to understand what is going on. So if I could persuade you to give me a quick line or 2 on what the above code does, that would be epic :)